# Sub pages result in 404

Tags: 7

I'm running Drupal 7, and I've cleared the cache through drush many times (drush cc all). I'm trying to access any subsequent pages beyond the front page and it results in a "Object not found error" error.

Does anyone have any idea? I feel like it's most likely an Apache or site configuration issue but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: How does the link look? Is it an 404 from Drupal or one from Apache? If Apache, My blind guess would be that clean URL's aren't working...

Comment: it's from apache. "Object not found" you're probably right there!

Comment: Shoot.. guess it was already turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the problem is that clean URL's are enabled in Drupal but not supported by your Apache configuration (make sure that mod_rewrite is enabled and the folder/vhost has AllowOverrides enabled) or the .htaccess file is missing.

You can verify that this is the problem by accessing the non-clean version of the URL. For example, instead of example.org/something, try example.org/?q=something.

See http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls for more information.

Comment: How would you enable AllowOverrides for the folder/vhost ? That's usually in the /opt/lampp/etc/http.conf file correct?

Comment: Add `AllowOverrides All`. Search for that on the linked page for more details.

Comment: Ah `AllowOverride All` without the 's'

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line in the .htaccess worked for me,

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

so it would now be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```